# How should I use after_create with a condition in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, after-create

I have a method that is called after the creation of an object

```
after_create :send_welcome_email
```

Is there a way to limit this to a condition, such as the value of an attribute of an object

```
after_create :send_welcome_email unless self.role == "Celebrant"
```

for example?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are three ways to do this: Symbol, String, or Proc.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :send_welcome_email, unless: :is_celebrant?
  after_create :send_welcome_email, unless: "is_celebrant?"
  after_create :send_welcome_email, unless: Proc.new { self.role == "Celebrant" }

end
```

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)

Comment: the documentation details have been moved to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol)