# undefined local variable or method after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'm getting this error when the after_create callback is executed in an activerecord model.

first of all, I have 2 after_create callbacks, one should run for everyone, and the other should only run if the user is a sibling:

```
  # callbacks
  after_create :couple_with_role 
  after_create :enroll_in_plan, :match_to_sibling, if: :is_sibling?

  def is_sibling?
    roles.include?('sibling')
  end
```

and the error looks like this:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `is_sibling' for
>   //User:0x007ffcae55c618// Did you mean?  is_sibling?

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little typo in your `if`. The correct way to do this is :

```
after_create :enroll_in_plan, :match_to_sibling, if: -> { is_sibling? }
```

Comment: @duxfox-- Ok. I've edited my answer, could you try that way ?

Comment: I just tried it, still getting the same error... this is really strange

Comment: it worked when I changed the method signature to `is_sibling` without the question mark

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as:

```
after_create :couple_with_role 
after_create :enroll_in_plan, :match_to_sibling, if: Proc.new { |user| user.roles.include?('sibling') }
```

[Read Using :if and :unless with a Symbol](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol)

[Using :if and :unless with a Proc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-proc)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `is_sibling?` method signature and removed the question mark, so now its `is_sibling` and it works like this:

```
after_create :enroll_in_plan, :match_to_sibling, if: :is_sibling
```

but why?

Answer (score 0):

you can use it with proc see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol)

```
after_create :normalize_card_number, if: :paid_with_card?
```

or you can pass a Proc to if clause

```
  after_create :enroll_in_plan, if: :is_sibling?

  def enroll_in_plan
  end
  def is_sibling?
  end
```

This also works for rails 4

Comment: that's exactly what I have but its not working with the '?' in the method name

Comment: as referenced in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314493/how-should-i-use-after-create-with-a-condition-in-the-model

is it working with proc for you if you action body into inline proc?